# Отступы между элементами в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Как сделать отступы между итемами в `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Как вариант поставить marginTop и marginBottom корневому элементу разметки итема

Comment: еще есть целый класс для оформления внешнего вида айтемов - [ItemDecoration](https://proandroiddev.com/itemdecoration-in-android-e18a0692d848)

Comment: @pavlofff, да, но ТС нужны только отступы, я не стал про него писать

Comment: Отступы -- это padding, margin -- это поля. ТС хочет увеличить расстояние между айтемами, для этого нужно настраивать `ItemDecorator`. Решение через отступы или поля айтема -- не очень хорошо, ибо они повлияют на начало и/или на конец списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под отступами. Есть 2 атрибута, которые влияют на "отступы" - *margin* и *padding*, соотношение между ними лучше всего показывает следующая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что вы решите что вам нужно и примените или `android:layout_margin` или `android:padding`